# How can I set ItemsSource for ComboBox inside the DataTemplate in code behind?(UWP)

Tags: combobox, grid, uwp

I have used below code to bind itemssource for MsComboBox in codebehind, which is not working.

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
            sb1.Append(@"<DataTemplate                                             xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource='{Binding ComboBoxItems, Source={StaticResource viewModel1}}'  Height='30' Width='100'  />              
                        </DataTemplate>");
            DataTemplate celltemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(sb1.ToString());
```

I can't refer Resource key from XAML.

Any suggest idea how to achieve this and Why the ItemsSource not bind for combobox?

Regards,
Srinivasan

Comment: Loading xaml codes with binding in code-behind is not a good idea. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have using like this:   StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
            sb1.Append(@"<DataTemplate xmlns:local='using:SfDataGridDemo'                                        xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'>
                          <ComboBox>
            <ComboBoxItem>
                Apple
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>
                Orange
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>
                Pine
            </ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>");

Comment: The above code has been working. Items populate in comboBox. Why can't we bind itemssource using xaml.?

Comment: I made a demo and reproduced the problem. It seems the loaded xaml can't find the already existing xaml that has been compiled. If you want to change the DataTemplate at runtime ,please use [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx).